# Handle Push Notification infos before login

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

My question is about a best practice to use to handle a push notification in a defined scenario.
My app has 3 ViewControllers:

- Login: User authenticates to start using the app
- TableView: A simple table view with a contacts like appearance
- DetailView: A simple viewController containing details from selected row of TableView

I receive a remote notification with some info in the payload (let's say a phone number for example). I need to use that info on DetailView but at receiving time I'm not logged in (app not running), so I press notification and it opens my app (Login) but I need to keep somewhere notification payload (or an object created from it) and pass it to DetailView.

So question is:
what is best practice to pass data from the notification to an inner ViewController, if the notification is received before user is logged in?

My only solution right now is: evaluate an object in `didReceiveRemoteNotification`, keep it in AppDelegate and access it everytime user's login to open DetailView if object is present (and clean it after using of course) but I don't think it is a good one.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you said is mostly right because the only place you will receive a notification in is your app delegate.

but keeping a global object with the data is not the right thing to do, specially if you would like to respect design pattern and isolation between the classes.

as I understand from you the data you will get in the payload will be used in other screens in the app, so what I think the best is :

save it in User defaults or data base and access it when ever you need, and keep overriding it every time you a new notification.

if you would like to use the data base option I would like to recommend you to use Realm as it way much easier than core data and didn't take much time implementing it.

Hint: if this is the only kind of data you gonna save in the app then use User defaults.

hope this answer your question

Comment: Thank for your response ahmed. Yes, my thoughts about isolation and design pattern related to global object were the same. The only problem I can see in saving an object somewhere is that developer MUST remember to clean it after using it and this scares me a little bit...

Comment: Yes you are right about that, I would like to recommend you to make a Util file for your user defaults that take care of saving, getting and cleaning the user default "if it will be your choice". and in your getter method make it take a Bool flag, if it is the last time you will need this data set the flag by true and in your method if the flag is true delete the data after getting it, this way you won't forget about it :)

Answer (score 0):

try to save this data in `User Defaults` then, when you are logged in, get the data from `User Defaults`. Second option - set some `variable` and initialize it whit this data, and after that pass the data to new `ViewController`/

Comment: yes, this is same as saving it on global variables (except that if app crashes information is still here but at this time I don't care to keep infos if it crashes). It is similar to my solution but I'm asking if this is the only solution or there is something better :)

Comment: I dont't tell about global variable, but about variable in AppDelegate in this case. Then you can have an access to this variable using for example `let x = UIApplication.shared.variable`

Comment: yes, I understand what you mean, but is same as I wrote on my question: _keep it in AppDelegate and access it everytime user's login to open DetailView if object is present_

Comment: in my opinion is save to save this data in `User Defaults`. Each time when become a new notification, previous data will be overridden